# free drawing on a touch screen, interacting with physical objects

Tags: led, sensor, lcd, touchscreen, drawing

I am an hobbyist and having a plan to create my own drawing tablet, and still making ideas, I want to combine physical world with this thing, an idea that I have is that I want line that I draw with my thumb to be wider than the line that I draw pinky finger without having to change the line width using code!

I am still researching why such thing doesn't exist, hope you can guide me!

My question is: is it about hardware and that we can't track every touched pixel?
Why cant every pixel be a touch sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touch sensor (electrode array) sits *on top* of the display. If every pixel were a touch sensor you couldn't see the screen below it. But you don't need a 1:1 relationship to get high resolution touch. Your fingers are three orders of magnitude bigger than a pixel.

In older (or cheap) sensors, the touch sensor grid was not high enough resolution:

[image]

However, it really is not a problem with modern sensors.

In fact, the raw sensor does what you describe, but finger-to-finger variation is undesirable in mouse pointing applications, so the drivers usually try to reduce the pressed area to a single point (typically centroid).

Here you can see one of many applications that uses a higher-resolution touch sensor to do exactly what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you this is informative! and good to know that its more about drivers!, but is it of high qulaity to detect a real painting brush strokes?! would it respond to the brush like the paper does?!

Comment: Resistive systems would not be high enough resolution. Capacitive systems won't detect your brush at all. You'd have to use your finger(s).

Comment: so with todays engineering or hardware such thing is not possible?

Comment: If you want to detect objects of low permittivity, you can do it, just not with the common technologies used in cell phone/tablet touch-screens. You need something [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n94E3IeBquY). They use the shadows cast by the object (there is a camera underneath the table looking up).

Comment: i have already done my DIY multi touch table and did everything i wanted with it, it detects the painting brush nicely but also not perfectly like on paper ,i wanted to move this to a portable device i guess after alot of research i realized its only possible to detect the brush strokes only with a camera, other solution i thoght about is making this device detect the physical brush i am using then simulate its stroke by software